# Jquery .html() function returns html out of nested order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a method which returns a persisted html template from a database.

The template is of the format:

```
<div id="item_collection">
     <div id="item_x">
      <p id="item_x_headline"><h2>Some Headline</h2></p>
      <p id="item_x_excerpt>Some text here</p>
     </div>
    <div id="item_x+1">
      <p id="item_x+1_headline"><h1>Some Headline</h1></p>
      <p id="item_x+1_excerpt>Some text here</p>
     </div>
    ...and so on.
</div>
```

However after I run the following:

```
alert(data); //check that the template is in order. It Is.
$('#template_area').html(data);
```

the Html is now:

```
<div id="item_collection">
     <div id="item_x">
      <p id="item_x_headline"></p> <!--Note The Lack of Nesting -->
      <h2>Some Headline</h2>
      <p id="item_x_excerpt>Some text here</p>
     </div>
    <div id="item_x+1">
      <p id="item_x+1_headline"></p> <!--Note The Lack of Nesting -->
      <h1>Some Headline</h1>
      <p id="item_x+1_excerpt>Some text here</p>
     </div>
    ...and so on.
</div>
```

So what gives? Is there a better way to replace the empty template_area's content than the .html() method?

EDIT: Solved. replacing paragraphs with divs yields the correct nesting. Jquery: writing better html than I since 2006.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<h2>` tag is not a valid child of `<p>`

Comment: Do you mean it is *not* a valid child of p?

Comment: Yes, he means it is not a valid child of <p>

Comment: Yes. The h2 tag is not a valid child of p.

Comment: Yes I did, added the missing not.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html

> Block structuring elements include
>   paragraphs, lists, and block quotes.
>   They must **not** contain heading
>   elements, but they may contain phrase
>   markup, and in some cases, they may be
>   nested.

Answer (score 1):

Am I seeing a quote mismatch in the `<p>` tag?

You are starting a double quote in the id=" and it is not ended properly.

```
<p id=**"**item_x_excerpt>Some text here</p>
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my pseudo code, the actual code doesn't reflect that. good eyes though :)